# cordova-plugin-geofence issue on mock location

Tags: angular, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, ionic2, android-geofence

I have initiated and added geofence in the application following https://github.com/tsubik/ionic2-geofence tutorial. If the set geofence is my current location, i am getting the notification successfully. But if i set geofence to some other location, notification is not triggered. Unable to track the issue as well.

I am using Lockito application to mock my location. Also enabled allow mock-location in my device.

Please help me by letting know what am i missing.

My code so far:

```
geo= {
      id: new_id,
      latitude: this.myLat,
      longitude: this.myLng,
      radius: 1000,
      transitionType: 1,
      notification: {
        id: new_id,
        title: "Title",
        text: "text",
        openAppOnClick: true,
      }
    };

geofence.addOrUpdate(geo)
        .then(() => this.findById(geo.id))
        .then((found) => {
          if (!found) {
            this.geofences.push(geo);
          } else {
            const index = this.geofences.indexOf(found);
            this.geofences[index] = geo;
          }
        });
```

Comment: Where is your code? What is the actual output/error? What have you tried so far, to fix this? Please read the following: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Tom Lord, i have not included the code as my code is working on my current location. My output is to get notification on entering region. I am not receiving any error. My actual problem is that i am not getting notification (output) on setting some other mock location. I have tried to enable location in device, added permission to my application as well. Hope i have mentioned all these in my question